# Knockout js taking more RAM memory

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockout js in one of my projects. I am new to knockout and I am struggling to fix the memory leaks in my project. My page is taking almost 100MB RAM on initial load and it keep on increasing by 17MB on every action user performs on the screen.

The main case that I feel where memory leaks is happening is the DOM rendering case. In the page some elements are added to DOM by looping through the observable array. Each time new set data comes I am just making the array empty and reloading it with new data, which will cause the DOM elements to be removed and added again with new data.

Can any one tell how these old DOM elements can disposed before they are removed so that they wont take RAM memory.

Knockout foreach binding:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Supplies">
        <tr>
            <td> <span data-bind="text:supplyName"></span>

            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options:supplyDetails,optionsText:'itemcapacity',value:selectedSupply"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

You can find the JS fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/Yu83N/8/

In the above fiddle. On initial page load I am populating the "Category" dropdown. When user changes "Category" the "Model" dropdown gets populated. On change of which I am fetching the supplies and loading observable array. So each time user changes "Model" dropdown, the supplies DOM will be created. Will the DOM takes more memory if so how can we dispose the old DOM elements to free up the memory?

Comment: Should we be expecting the memory jump when hitting your fiddle? I'm not seeing any sizable jump when I view it in chrome. I suppose it's because your example doesn't have as big of a sample set to recreate the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the fiddle works? Choosing a Model for me just throws Javascript errors and never shows any supplies. The scenario you describe should work fine - setting an observable array to an empty array will cause Knockout to automatically clean up the DOM elements and remove them - so something else is wrong. Please post a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I am really sorry for providing wrong fiddler, I have updated the fiddler now, please check now.

Comment: i agree there is no high memory jump, max i had was 2 mb when loading your fiddle, you should use the chrome's memory profiling tool and see for yourself. :), maybe the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Heap comparisons using Chrome 35.0 on the new fiddle show no leaks when you change the Model. It is cleaning up DOM elements perfectly. Maybe provide a different fiddle that demonstrates the "increasing by 17MB on every action" problem.

Comment: I have not posted my complete code which loads 17MB every time. But I see whenever I change the "Model" drop down list there is some increment in the memory. The same can observed by clicking the button1,button2 alternatively. Is the increase in memory(here it is 10 to 20KB) when new DOM is getting created is it common behavior of Knockout?

The same "supplies" DOM elements are getting rendered in 10 different places on my page.

Comment: If you have custom binding handlers, you'll want to use `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal` to clean up after them when they're removed from the DOM.